# Is there a way to use compareTo with double? Java

Tags: java

I was wondering is it possible to compare 2 double elements from arraylist with compareTo? I've tried something like, but everyone knows that I will receive and error, but still I want to use this compareTo if it's possible.

```
prekiuArray.stream().sorted((p1, p2) -> p1.getPrice().compareTo(p2.getPrice())).forEach(p -> System.out.printf("%s%n", p));
```

Comment: Using the comment above. You can also rewrite your code as below including comments and answers:
`prekiuArray.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(MyClass::getPrice)).forEach(System.out::println);`

Answer (score 4):

`double` is a primitive and has no methods. `Double` (the boxed version) implements `Comparable`, so you can use `compareTo` on that, or you can use [`Double.compare(double d1, double d2)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare(double,%20double)) to compare primitives

The best way to solve this does not involve a lambda at all. You can use [`Comparator.comparingDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingDouble-java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction-) and pass it a method reference:

```
... .stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(MyClass::getPrice)) ...
```

`Comparator.comparing` would be used instead of `comparingDouble` if `getPrice` returned a boxed `Double` to avoid unboxing it unnecessarily.

Answer (score 3):

You may do it like so,

```
prekiuArray.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(Prekiu::.getPrice()))
                .forEach(p -> System.out.printf("%s%n", p));
```